# Gamma hurdle model for continuous response?

Tags: r, regression, glmm, biostatistics, zero-inflation

I am modelling `invertebrate.biomass ~ habitat.type * calendar.day + habitat.type * calendar.day ^ 2`, with a random intercept of `transect.id` (50 transects were repeated 5 times)

My response is zero-heavy - about 25% are 0s - and the non-zeroes are strongly right-skewed.

I understand a possible way of dealing with this is to construct 2 models - one modelling a binary response in a logistic regression and the other modelling the non-zero response in a (e.g.) Gamma regression. I'm working in R and following the ideas in [this post](http://seananderson.ca/2014/05/18/gamma-hurdle.html).

I want to check the method of combining the results of these 2 models, in order to generate quantitative predictions (ultimately with CI). Am I correct in multiplying the predicted probabilities from the logistic regression with the predicted (non-zero) biomass from the Gamma regression? Thus, the predicted (non-zero) biomass gets down-weighted according to the probability of there actually being an invertebrate present at all. This makes sense in my head, but feels too easy to be true.

See plots below which demonstrate my method in it's current form.

[image: Gamma hurdle model]

Assuming I'm right so far, how would I then go about generating a SE / CI for the predictions combining two models?

Comment: Yes, your intuition is correct, see here: https://seananderson.ca/2014/05/18/gamma-hurdle/

Note that there is a bit of funny-business going on when he computes the population mean as $\exp(\log(\text{bin_coef}) + \log(\text{gamma_coef}))$, but note that this just simplifies down to $\text{bin_coef}\cdot \text{gamma_coef}$

Comment: You could bootstrap for SEs and CIs

Answer (score 1):

Your plots show that your response variable is confined between 0 and 1, where beta regression may work well. There is zero-, one-, and zero-one-inflated beta regression via gamlss::gamlss(). You can also check the {betareg} for basic operations. See Korosteleva, O. (2019). Advanced regression models with SAS and R. CRC Press.

For zero-inflated beta regression, you could also use the package {glmmTMB} `glmmTMB(zi = ~ , family = beta_family())`. Its likelihood function has both the zero inflation and beta regression, which is why their uncertainty (standard error and variance-covariance) is estimated together and more efficient than your manually multiplying from two different models. It also fits zero-inflated gamma regression, `glmmTMB(zi = ~ , family = ziGamma(link = "inverse"))`. Another implementation of zero inflated gamma regression is https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/Rfast2/html/zigamma.reg.html

After fitting, you can generate prediction plots with confidence intervals using the {marginaleffects} package.